# SetState with data from React-query with React/Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-query

I am trying to set the state using setState and it needs to default to the data from React-query, but on refresh it says `undefined`.

```
const fetchAlerts = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
    return res.json();
};

 const { data, status } = useQuery('todos', fetchTodos, {
    staleTime: 5000,
});

const result = data;

const [fetchData, setFetchData] = React.useState<ITodo[]>(result);
```

then I map over the state object like:

```
{fetchData.map() etc}
```

Comment: „Why do you need to do that“ would be my counter question? Every background refetch from react-query will overwrite the local state with the useEffect solutions, so why not just use the data from useQuery directly? I see no reason to sync state like that…

Comment: I have filter buttons which I am filtering the array by updating the state and showing the results

Comment: So my counter question would be, how would I do that without using state?

Comment: for example, you can store the filter criteria (that the user selects) only and then perform the filtering in the render function. If it's expensive, you can apply `useMemo`. But storing derived state is rarely the solution because you create two sources of truth.

Comment: a "filtered list" is even one of the examples in the react-docs for something that is NOT state: https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-3-identify-the-minimal-but-complete-representation-of-ui-state

Comment: Ok, I understand so can you give a code example? so I can see what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have set up a working example in the sandbox, you need to set the state data in `useEffect` and to wrap your app with `QueryClientProvider` to use `userQuery` successfully "just to mention that"

[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-bas-h6l4r?file=/src/App.tsx)

// Alert component

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import "./styles.css";

interface ITodo {
  userId: string;
  id: string;
  title: string;
}

const fetchAlerts = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");
  return res.json();
};

export default function Component() {
  const [fetchData, setFetchData] = React.useState<ITodo[]>([]);

  const { data, status } = useQuery<ITodo[]>("mytodos", fetchAlerts, {
    staleTime: 5000
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setFetchData(data ?? []);
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {fetchData.map((x) => (
        <li>
          {" "}
          {x.userId} - {x.id} - {x.title.substr(10)}
        </li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

// App component

```
import "./styles.css";
import Component from "./component";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";
export default function App() {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <div className="App">
        <Component />
      </div>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you not supposed to pass a query in the array for useEffect?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. See [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-meadow-owq6z?file=/src/App.js) here for working example.

```
function Example() {
  const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = React.useState([]);

  const fetchTodos = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");
    return res.json();
  };

  const { data: result } = useQuery("todos", fetchTodos, {
    staleTime: 5000
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setFetchedData(result);
  }, [result]);

  return <p>{JSON.stringify(fetchedData)}</p>;
}
```

Comment: For the `setFetchedData(result) ` I am getting 'Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.'

Comment: have you got this line, or something else? `const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = React.useState([]);` if you are using `setState` it should be expecting an arg.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I have got it working with the previous answer, although both very similar - I would mark both if I could

Comment: you're welcome!